# What is destroying the process memory?

Tags: node.js, memory, process, heroku

```
2012-07-20T03:04:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=546M(106.8%)
2012-07-20T03:04:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:05:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=583M(113.9%)
2012-07-20T03:05:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:05:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=611M(119.4%)
2012-07-20T03:05:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:05:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=611M(119.4%)
2012-07-20T03:05:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:06:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=605M(118.3%)
2012-07-20T03:06:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:06:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=689M(134.6%)
2012-07-20T03:06:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:06:37+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST vivid-night-1834.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-20T03:06:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=909M(177.7%)
2012-07-20T03:06:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2012-07-20T03:07:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=909M(177.7%)
```

Look at how quickly the process is running out of memory. I ran heroku restart and it's still happening a second later.

I've a node.js app which I've been working on without any difficulties really for the past couple of days. It makes some mongodb calls, some redis calls, but the combined amount of data both in redis and mongo is probably under 50kb.

How do I track the issue down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the changes you made between when it was working and now, perhaps?

Without seeing the code, it'll be hard to say much about what the problem could be, except that you're obviously doing something to allocate memory over and over, so that's either a loop, or a recursive function call without a proper exit condition.

Comment: Yeah I did go back and try it right after I posted here. I narrowed it down to a faulty for() loop but I can't figure out why it's going endlessly for the life of me, looks like any other loop.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it was your loop, but memory quota exceeding is a common issue most of the developer face with heroku. It has something to do with Node's Garbage Collector. I am putting my answer here to help those guys who might have been searching for the same issue.

> Node (V8) uses a lazy and greedy garbage collector. With its default limit of about 1.5 GB, it sometimes waits until it absolutely has to before reclaiming unused memory. If your memory usage is increasing, it might not be a leak - but rather node's usual lazy behavior.
>   To gain more control over your app's garbage collector, you can provide flags to V8 in your `Procfile`:
>
> This is especially important if your app is running in an environment
>   with less than 1.5 GB of available memory. For example, if you'd like
>   to tailor node to a 512 MB container, try:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 server.js
```

taken from here https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016